# Unable to get web element since XPATH is dynamically changing

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

```
<div dojoattachpoint="titleNode" class="dijitTitlePaneTextNode" tabindex="0">Transfer ( XXXXX.YYYYYY@ABCD.COM 10-Aug-2021 02:24:39 PM  GMT+05:30 )  <a href="#topPortion">Top</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#bottomPortion">Bottom</a></div>
```

The above snippet I got from inspect element on Google Chrome. I am want to get this "Transfer ( XXXXX.YYYYYY@ABCD.COM 10-Aug-2021 02:24:39 PM  GMT+05:30 ) " value to be printed in output.

The problem is that XPATH get changed dynamically every time.

I have already tried the below, but it did not work.

```
get_div = driver.find_element_by_class_name("dijitTitlePaneTextNode")
get_div = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(), "Transfer ( ")]')
get_div = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class = "dijitTitlePaneTextNode"]')
```

Comment: In your comments below, you state that there are many of these HTML blocks on the page... how do you know which one you want? Is it labelled somehow? Please edit your question and add more of the surrounding HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this CSS selector and see if that helps:

```
div[dojoattachpoint='titleNode']
```

in code:

```
get_div = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[dojoattachpoint='titleNode']")
print(get_div.text)
```

if it needs explicit wait:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
a = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[dojoattachpoint='titleNode']"))).text
print(a)
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Update 1 :**

The below xpath should represent the first element,

```
(//div[@dojoattachpoint='titleNode'])[1]
```

and the below should represent the 2nd one..

```
(//div[@dojoattachpoint='titleNode'])[2]
```

so using xpath indexing you can get the unique match.

Comment: Actually, I have many titleNode in that page. I get different result instead of "Transfer ( XXXXX.YYYYYY@ABCD.COM 10-Aug-2021 02:24:39 PM GMT+05:30 ) "

Comment: @HemapriyaViswanath : Check out the updated 1 answer above, and let me know if you run into any issue.

Comment: It fails. I have many "Transfer ( " line in that web page, all those XPATH's are changing dynamically. and many titleNode. div[dojoattachpoint='titleNode'] works but it is pulling some other line.


```    get_div = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("""(//div[@dojoattachpoint='titleNode'])[1]""")
  File "C:\Users\suumapat\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 598, in find_element_by_css_selector
    return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
 ....
````

Comment: actually that was xpath, not css selector, `driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@dojoattachpoint='titleNode'])[1]")` try this instead.

Comment: Thank you @cruisepandey. thanks for the clue. I changed [1] to [22] but I could not get the exact "transfer ( " values

Comment: Is it possible to share webpage ?

Comment: Problem is... it is a intranet webpage! need to connect via vpn.... when I test it, every time I login, do some steps then I get this page. I can show you thru zoom! or any means

Comment: it works till [22] if i keep [23] it fails with... I have a text as "Transfer ( " is unique... how to take this?

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//div[@dojoattachpoint='titleNode'])[23]"}
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.159)

Comment: May be that is not in selenium view port. Can you share page resource ?

Comment: the page is intranet :(  zoom is okay?

Comment: how can i share the web source?

Comment: You need to save the source code into a text file, then upload that text file using file sharing website (free ofcourse). they will give you a sharable link. That link you can give me.

Comment: `print(driver.page_source)` this should give you page resource

Comment: Hello Pandey, here you go... https://ufile.io/l9apavq0

I am looking for "Transfer ( " that line to be printed!!!!

Comment: This always varies.... different page.. I get different emails... and many TRANSFER lines...

Comment: Yes, it might be at the little up to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Consider `driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")` to scroll till end and then try to scrape the data

Comment: Hello Cruisepandey, still it is fails for 23rd index always.

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//div[@dojoattachpoint='titleNode'])[23]"}
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.159)

Comment: this is the code

        if click_all:
            click_all.click()
            driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
            gets1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@dojoattachpoint='titleNode'])[23]")
            print(gets1.text)

Comment: Basically, you need to scroll till that element, so selenium can see it, it does not have eyes :P, so you have to let Selenium know where is exactly the element is, if the above scrolling does not work, try this `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, Y)") `, where Y is vertical scrolling, you can give 100, or 200 , may be even 1000, just try with all the Y values, and see if scrolling is actually visible when you run your suite

Comment: driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")

Resolved the issue.. One help. Request you to delete one of your post which contains Transfer ( xxx.xxxx@xxxx.xxx25-Jun-2021 03:22:05 PM  GMT+05:30 )

Comment: Alright, Sounds good ! Was it helpful ?if yes, can you accept this answer so that it will be available in green color for future readers. In case if you would like to accept this answer, please feel free click on check mark which is right aside with voting buttons. I'd appreciate your time and response on this. –